# Can I make a single binary write for a C++ struct which contains a vector

Tags: c++, struct, stdvector

I am trying to build and write a binary request and have a "is this possible" type question. It might be important for me to mention the recipiant of the request is not aware of the data structure I have included below, it's just expecting a sequence of bytes, but using a struct seemed like a handy way to prepare the pieces of the request, then write them easily.

Writing the header and footer is fine as they are fixed size but I'm running into problems with the struct "Details", because of the vector. For now Im writing to a file so I can check the request is to spec, but the intention is to write to a PLC using boost asio serial port eventually

I can use syntax like so to write a struct, but that writes pointer addresses rather than values when it gets to the vector

```
myFile.write((char*) &myDataRequest, drSize);
```

I can use this sytax to write a vector by itself, but I must include the indexer at 0 to write the values

```
myFile.write((char*) &myVector[0], vectorSize);
```

Is there an elegant way to binary write a struct containing a vector (or other suitable collection), doing it in one go? Say for example if I declared the vector differently, or am I resigned to making multiple writes for the content inside the struct. If I replace the vector with an array I can send the struct in one go (without needing to include any indexer) but I dont know the required size until run time so I don't think it is suitable.

My Struct

```
    struct Header
    {   ...     };

    struct Details
    {
           std::vector<DataRequest> DRList;
    };

    struct DataRequest
    {
           short numAddresses;          // Number of operands to be read   Bytes 0-1
           unsigned char operandType;   //                                  Byte 2
           unsigned char Reserved1;     //Should be 0xFF                    Byte 3
           std::vector<short> addressList;  // either, starting address (for sequence), or a list of addresses (for non-sequential) 
    };

    struct Footer
    {   ...     };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible because the `std::vector` object doesn't actually contain an array but rather a pointer to a block of memory. However, I'm tempted to claim that being able to write a raw struct like that is not desireable:

1. I believe that by treating a struct as a block of memory you may end up sending padding bytes, I don't think this is desireable.
2. Depending on what you write to you may find that writes are buffered anyway, so multiple write calls aren't actually less efficient.
3. Chances are that you want to do *something* with the fields being sent over. In particular, with the numeric values you send. This requires enforcing a byte order which both sides of the transmission agree on. In order to be portable, you should exlicitely convert the byte order to make sure that your software is portable (if this is required).

To make a long story short: I suspect writing out each field one by one is not less efficient, it also is more correct.

Comment: thanks, this is all I'm looking for here, some advice on a correct strategy.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a good strategy, since even if you could do this you're copying memory content directly to file. If you change the architecture/processor your client will get different data. If you write a method taking your struct and a filename, which writes the structs values individually and iterates over the vector writing out its content, you'll have full control over the binary format your client expects and are not dependent on the compilers current memory representation.

If you want convenience for marshalling/unmarshalling you should take a look at the [boost::serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) library. They do offer a binary archive (besides text and xml) but it has its own format (e.g. it has a version number, which serialization lib was used to dump the data) so it is probably not what your client wants.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is the format expected at the other end?  You have to write
that, period.  You can't just write any random bytes.  The probability
that just writing an `std::vector` like you're doing will work is about
as close to 0 as you can get.  But the probability that writing a
`struct` with only `int` will work is still less than 50%.  If the other
side is expecting a specific sequence of bytes, then you have to write
that sequence, byte by byte.  To write an `int`, for example, you must 
still write four (or whatever the protocol requires) bytes, something
like:

```
byte[0] = (value >> 24) & 0xFF;
byte[1] = (value >> 16) & 0xFF;
byte[2] = (value >>  8) & 0xFF;
byte[3] = (value      ) & 0xFF;
```

(Even here, I'm supposing that your internal representation of negative
numbers corresponds to that of the protocol.  Usually the case, but not
always.)

Typically, of course, you build your buffer in a `std::vector<char>`,
and then write `&buffer[0], buffer.size()`.  (The fact that you need a
`reinterpret_cast` for the buffer pointer should signal that your
approach is wrong.)

Comment: Your code is actually equivalent to [`htonl`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/htonl.html) I think.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe Maybe.  On some platforms.  But of course, we don't know if that's the actual bytes he needs.  I just popped it in as an example of how you have to go about doing things.  (And of course, with `htonl`, you still have to assign the results to a `uint32_t`, then copy that bytewise into the buffer, since `htonl` doesn't take care of alignment issues.)